Storing blog author name and publish data to GA4
I want to be able to filter by the blog publish date and blog author in GA4?
What would be the recommended way to send this data to Google Analytics?

You can use custom dimensions at the event level: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/14239696
Beware that if there are more than 500 authors you can get cardinality when you generate a report that contains them all:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12226705?hl=en

Would you add a custom dimension to the page_view event or create a totally new event?

Considering that an author refers to an article on a page, it makes sense to associate it with the page_view event
